# Upsert with Mongoskin (node.js and mongodb)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, upsert

I'm learning node.js and mongodb.  I'm using the mongoskin module in my app, but I can't seem to get "upsert" functionality to work.

I've read the (rather opaque) mongoskin guide on github.  Here's what I've tried so far:

```
// this works.  there's an insert then an update.  The final "x" is "XX".
db.collection("stuff").insert({a:"A"}, {x:"X"});
db.collection("stuff").update({a:"A"}, {x:"XX"});

// this does NOT work.  I thought it would do an upsert, but nothing.
db.collection("stuff").update({b:"B"}, {y:"YY"}, true);
```

How can I create "update or insert if not exists" functionality?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've not tried it, but according to the doc here: https://github.com/guileen/node-mongoskin#inherit-updating and here: https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/docs/insert.md, it looks like `options` is the third parameter, and it's supposed to be an object, like so:

```
db.collection("stuff").update({b:"B"}, {y:"YY"}, {upsert:true});
```